# IE Select Box option element height not working

Tags: html, css

select item option lists are not showing properly in IE.

[image]

need to add padding and height for option element. Does any one knows how to fix this?

**CSS**

```
.reser_item_long select {
width: 106%;
width: 106.5%\9;
height: 33px;
*height: 33px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;

background: none;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10px;
color: #889099;
color: #889099\9 !important;
padding: 9px 0 0 7px;
padding: 0 0 0 7px\9 ;
padding: 0 0 0 7px\0/;
display:block;  
(-bracket-:hack;
   padding: 2px 0 0 7px ;
);
```

}

**HTML**

```
    <div class="reser_item_long">               
    <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select id="cmb-country" name="cmb-country">
    <option value="-1">Please Select a Country</option>
    <option value="0">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="0">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="0">Albania</option>
    <option value="0">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code or a test case to debug?

Comment: what exactly do u want!!!! i didn't get u...

Comment: Show what CSS you're using for the individual options in the list

Comment: @GreenWizard i need to add padding between options

Comment: @Mr.Alien I've updated with the source code.can you pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no work-around for this aside from ditching the select element

Answer (score 2):

You should differently edit this question and add you browser version. But let me give you a solution after all.

The problem is that the Select, options, file inputs are rendered by the OS/Browser and not by the HTML itself and therefor give's problem in styling it.

You can via javascript simulate and style your own dropdown to make sure it looks the same way in every browser and OS. Basically it generates something that look and feels like a dropdown list but is just an interface for the hidden select in your code.

You could use something like http://formalize.me/ to style all forms elements on your page.